# Receiving error with mcar test using library naniar

Tags: r

I'm running the mcar_test and I'm getting the following error. Any ideas as to what it could be!?

```
> print(file)
# A tibble: 1,000 x 10
     Obs Grocery_Bill N_Adults Family_Income Family_Size N_Vehicles Distance_to_Store Vegetarian N_Children Family_Pet
   <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1         358.        2        142141           4          3                15          0          2          1
 2     2         277.        2        145916           2          1                 4          0          0          0
 3     3         198.        1         86185           1          2                14          0          0          0
 4     4         316.        2        145998           3          1                 8          0          1          0
 5     5         203.        1         79341           1          2                19          1          0          0
 6     6         197.        1         77115           2          1                 2          0          1          1
 7     7         195.        1         73725           2          1                 4          0          1          0
 8     8         233.        1         88371           1          2                 8          0          0          0
 9     9         146.        1         75942           1          3                 8          0          0          0
10    10         125.        1         70298           1          0                 2          0          0          0
# ... with 990 more rows
```

```
mcar_test(file)
```

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `d2`.
i `d2 = purrr::pmap_dbl(...)`.
x system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.23398e-24
i The error occurred in group 1: miss_pattern = 1.
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm/76494#76494

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).